# Read the images and do the color changes (using Image or openCV) (Python)

Tags: python, image, opencv

Need to read the images and do the color changes illustrated below for each of the masks, as shown below.

[image: Should convert the red into a black background and the cut out shape into white]

I thought of first converting the black into white using: `imageWithMask = cv2.bitwise_not(image)`

I'm thinking they're two ways to do this
One split the image into two and change the colors
Other is to use a threshold and convert which I don't know properly, looking for any assistance with the same.

Comment: Do color thresholding on red using cv2.inRange() so that the red becomes white and the rest black. Then invert using result = 255 - result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## Read
img = cv2.imread("your_image_path.jpg")

## convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

## mask of lower red (0,50,50) ~ (10,255,255)
mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0,50,50), (10,255,255))

## mask of upper red (170,50,50) ~ (180,255,255)
mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, (170,50,50), (180,255,255))

## final mask and masked
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)

## target = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask)

inverseGrayImage = numpy.uint8(255) - mask;
plt.imshow(inverseGrayImage,cmap='gray')
cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", inverseGrayImage)
```